# How can I use a list as reference in Spring configuration for JAX-WS handlers?

Tags: spring, jax-ws

I am using the Spring extension for JAX-WS and have a problem to use a list in my Spring configuration:

This is the working configuration:

```
<wss:binding url="/services/demo">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#demoEndpoint">
            <ws:handlers>
                <ref bean="handler1"/>
                <ref bean="handler2"/>
            </ws:handlers>
        </ws:service>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

As I have more endpoint, which should use the same set of handlers, I want to define the list of handlers in a single configuration.

But this config doesn't work:

```
<util:list id="myHandlers">
    <ref bean="handler1"/>
    <ref bean="handler2"/>
</util:list>

<wss:binding url="/services/demo">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#demoEndpoint">
            <ws:handlers>
                <ref bean="myHandlers"/>
            </ws:handlers>
        </ws:service>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [javax.xml.ws.handler.Handler] for property 'handlers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
    ... 66 more
```

This is the corresponding setter in org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService:

```
public void setHandlers(List<Handler> handlers) {
    this.handlers = handlers;
}
```